# How can I reset rownames?

Tags: r

I have a data frame named lagcolmean like this which begins with 2, since I drop the first one

```
     MSFT     AAPL     GOOGL
2 20.91273 5.663524  97.50684
3 20.05333 5.681336  90.57909
4 20.09447 5.239416  99.60738
```

Now how can I convert it like this

```
    MSFT     AAPL     GOOGL
1 20.91273 5.663524  97.50684
2 20.05333 5.681336  90.57909
3 20.09447 5.239416  99.60738
```

I actually used  `rownames(lagcolmean)` but the output is this

```
 [1] "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11" 
 [11] "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21" 
 [21] "22"  "23
```

Comment: You can just set them to `NULL` which will automatically create new row names from 1:nrow(df): `rownames(df) <- NULL`

Comment: sorry for the duplication. It was my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your data frame is called `df`, just do `rownames(df)=NULL`

Comment: thank you so much RockScience

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
```